# recharts line chart not responsive inside a responsive container

Tags: reactjs, frontend, responsive, recharts

```
<div>
    <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height={400}>
      <LineChart
        data={data}
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="pv"
          stroke="#8884d8"
          activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
        />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </div>
```

**Rechart on desktop:**

[image: Rechart on desktop]

**Rechart when window is resized:**
[image: Rechart when window is resized]

Line chart is not responsive until I reload the page again,

**Rechart when window is reloaded:**
[image: Rechart when window is reloaded]

same things happen otherway around.

please see images to understand question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug.

what you can do is set ResponsiveContainer width to 99%

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height="100%">
     <chart here..../>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create new class

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
const useDeviceSize = () => {

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

const handleWindowResize = () => {
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  setHeight(window.innerHeight);
}

useEffect(() => {
  // component is mounted and window is available
  handleWindowResize();
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  // unsubscribe from the event on component unmount
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
}, []);

return [width, height]
```

}

export default useDeviceSize

2. import the new class in your chart class
3. put in your chart class

const [width, height] = useDeviceSize();

4. remove ResponsiveContainer tag
5. LineChart width={width/1.6}
6. note : 1.6 you can change it to what you see is suitable

Answer (score 0):

This is an known issue in current recharts version 2.1.0: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2620

You can downgrade to version 2.0.10 and the responsiveness will work again.

Comment: Can you please guide how to downgrade?

Comment: @BM.ZahidulIslam It might make sense to check out the latest recharts version. In general, in order to set a specific version of a library in use, you can visit package.json and set the desired version of the library there.

Comment: visited package.json and set the desired version of the library there but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Did you reinstall the packages afterwards with `npm install` or `yarn` (depending on the package manager you are using)? Your package-lock.json or yarn.lock file should indicate that you are using the respective version of the library.

Comment: I didn't try npm install after editing the package.json file.

Comment: You need to do that, otherwise the downgrade does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

remove ResponsiveContainer tags and try < LineChart width={window.screen.width} />